# How do I prevent my Game from accessing Microphone?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

For some reason, my Unity game asks for use of Microphone at start up.

Where in Xcode (or Unity) can I disable that request of accessing the microphone?

Comment: Is this happening only on iOS build? Did you tried web or android build? You can take a look at this: [Documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Microphone.html) but i'm not sure what could be happening. What is you unity version?

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure that you aren't running anything like `Application.RequestUserAuthorization(UserAuthorization.Microphone)` anywhere.

Second, according to [this guy on the Unity forums](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/589261/my-ios-app-doesnt-use-the-mic-but-the-app-asks-for.html), the only way to permanently disable asking for microphone permissions is by unchecking the `Prepare iOS for Recording` box in XCode and renaming the game.  I believe that the renaming portion only applies if you have submitted to Apple, in which case you would have to do a factory reset on your device (or just rename), but I cannot be completely sure.